# Is there any best practices for ER Diagram and fields length in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, erd

We want to create an online reservation system for restaurants. Here is our ER Diagram:
[image]

So my question is that since we've never created ER Diagram on our own (I'm Student) I'm curious what could we do better or what else should we add. There is one more thing to mention, we want to create Web-Application and Mobile-Application.

And my second question is if there is any resource where I could find the best practices values for `VARCHAR`, I've been googling it and there are different values each time. E.g. someone said for email the length should be `80` and someone said it should be `255` (default).

Here are our tables for now if the ER Diagram is right this should be right too.

```
DROP TABLE RESERVATION;
DROP TABLE RESTAURANT;
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;
DROP TABLE RESTAURANTOwner;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTOMER_ID INT primary key NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(255),
CUSTOMER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255), 
CUSTOMER_USERNAME VARCHAR(80), 
CUSTOMER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(80), 
CUSTOMER_PHONE VARCHAR(20) 
);

CREATE TABLE RESTAURANTOwner (
OWNER_ID INT primary key NOT NULL,
OWNER_NAME VARCHAR(255),
OWNER_EMAIL VARCHAR(255), 
OWNER_USERNAME VARCHAR(80), 
OWNER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(80), 
OWNER_PHONE VARCHAR(20) 
);

CREATE TABLE RESTAURANT (
RESTAURANT_ID INT primary key NOT NULL,
OWNER_ID INT NOT NULL,
RESTAURANT_NAME VARCHAR(255),
RESTAURANT_LAYOUT VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT FK_OWNER_ID FOREIGN key (OWNER_ID) references RESTAURANTOwner(OWNER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION (
RESTAURANT_ID INT NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID INT NOT NULL,
RESERVATION_TIME Time,
RESERVATION_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(RESTAURANT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,RESERVATION_TIME,RESERVATION_DATE),
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_ID FOREIGN key (CUSTOMER_ID) references CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RESTAURANT_ID FOREIGN key (RESTAURANT_ID) references RESTAURANT(RESTAURANT_ID)

);
```

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this? Do you fear that the database design itself is bad, or is this solely about the diagram?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm in fear of the database design.

Comment: Hi Kil Gore: Are you sure, 1 costumer booking 1 restaurant, not just 1 spot/table? Do you need start and end date time to?

Comment: @sukalogika Yea that is what is ment 1 costumer can book 1 table, there is no end time only start time e.g. 16 o'clock

Comment: You need extra table called: "table/spot" . Its need 1-M relation between restaurant and "table/spot". After that, reservation is between customer.customer_id and table.table_id

Comment: @sukalogika either than that everything is ok ?

Comment: about your 2nd question: You can keep data-type and length in reasonable space. Like: Maybe use UNSIGNED INT for your customer_id ; dont forget Auto_incr if you need. As student, thats all is good start Kil Gore :D , you can optimize later